# react router 6 route params

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to set up some react router routes, using the newest v6 specifically. What I'd like to do is have a website with a rest-like hierarchy of pages, and be able to parse out the IDs easily. Specifically with two level of IDs on the path.

I'm having trouble with how I'm supposed to properly parse out the IDs from the url using react router paradigms.  I could just use `window.location.pathname` and parse it myself or with a lib like it was 2003, but theres got to be a more react way to do it.

Here is the basic desired structure of urls:

```
/collection/          (all collections) 
/collection/123       (collection 123)
/collection/123/abc   (collection 123, subgroup abc)
/collection/123/all   (special handler, collection 123, all subgroups)
```

It seems I can use `useParams()`, however when I `console.log` that within my Screen it does not seem very helpful or structured at all.  See below.

**Should there be a better way to pull out the `:id` or `:groupId` specified in the routes?** Instead of just one property for "*" that I still end up needing to parse myself anyway.  I was hoping for a "id" and "groupId" property, but maybe I'm approaching it wrong.

```
// App.tsx
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/collection/*" element={<CollectionScreen />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

```
// CollectionScreen.tsx
const params = useParams()

console.log(params);
// {*: ''}        // path:  /collection
// {*: '123'}     // path:  /collection/123
// {*: '123/abc'} // path:  /collection/123/abc
 
...
 
<Routes>
  <Route path=":id/*" element={<Collection />} />
  <Route path=":id/all" element={<CollectionAll />} />
  <Route path=":id/:groupId" element={<CollectionGroup />} />
</Routes>
```

EDIT:
Based on solution below, this route structure does what I need. I didn't want to use the `element` in the subroutes in my App.tsx as things are a little more complicated and I want to keep App.tsx light. Removing the `element` property however works fine.  I then just use `useParams()` in the Screen to access all the params as I originally needed.

```
// App.tsx
<Route path="/collection/*" element={<CollectionsScreen />}>
  <Route path=":id/*" />
  <Route path=":id/all" />
  <Route path=":id/:groupId" />
</Route>

// CollectionScreen.tsx
const params = useParams<{ id?: string; groupId?: string }>();
const { id, groupId } = params;

...

// simplified here, but easy access to id/groupId here is helpful
{!id && <Collection />}
{id && groupId && groupId === "all" && <CollectionAll />}
{id && groupId && groupId !== "all" && <CollectionGroup />}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `useParams` hook only returns the route params within the current `Routes` component scope.

For example, if the path is `"/collection/123/456"` then:

- `CollectionScreen` sees `{*: "123/456"}`

  Where the `*` is from the parent `CollectionScreen` route.
- `CollectionGroup` sees `{*: "123/456", id: "123", groupId: "456"}`

  Where the `*` is from the parent `CollectionScreen` route and `id` and `groupId` from the child `CollectionGroup` component.

[image: Edit react-router-6-route-params]

The `CollectionScreen` can't see route params further down because it is rendering a `Routes` component which effectively "gates" the params below it. A small refactor of the routes can allow `CollectionScreen` to see the route params routes below it.

App

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/collection/*">
      <Route path=":id" element={<CollectionScreen />}>
        <Route index element={<Collection />} />
        <Route path="all" element={<CollectionAll />} />
        <Route path=":groupId" element={<CollectionGroup />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

CollectionScreen

```
const params = useParams();

console.log("CollectionScreen", params);

return (
  <>
    ...
    <Outlet />
  </>
);
```

[image: Edit react-router-6-route-params (forked)]

Now all routed components see the same `params` object.

> ```
> CollectionScreen {*: "123/456", id: "123", groupId: "456"}
> CollectionGroup {*: "123/456", id: "123", groupId: "456"}
> ```

Comment: This explains it well.  Moving the sub-routes to App are what worked best to get param access in the Screen where I needed it.  I tweaked it a bit to keep the heavy lifting outside of App.  See my edit above.

Comment: @Miro Ah, I see... that's pretty slick.